# Intent ACTION_SEND without default launch

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to share a text by my app using ACTION_SEND in the intent. But if you choose using an app for default, it will share with the same app without asking everytime.

Can someone help me with it?

if it's posible, it should be able to share via mail, facebook, twitter, whatsapp like this code do. Thanks.

```
Intent textShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            textShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share, URL");
            textShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(textShareIntent);
```

Comment: Do you want to launch Android's default chooser window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent textShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
textShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share, URL");
textShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
if (textShareIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(textShareIntent, "Share"));
else
    // no app can handle this intent, do something else
```